# WordPress/Avada - How to fix text wrapping around image on medium sized screens

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm working on a page built in Avada on WordPress.

If anybody is familiar with it, we're using content boxes to build out a vertical timeline, and everything is going well except for one small issue we need some help with.

On medium sized screens, some of the text awkwardly sticks to the side as in the image below. I am wondering if there is some CSS rule we can apply to it so that the text will stay below the image when it goes below full-screen size. It does that as soon as we are on small/phone screen sizes.

We haven't coded anything ourselves but the page-builder is using these rules:

```
p {
    display: block;
    margin-block-start: 1em;
    margin-block-end: 1em;
    margin-inline-start: 0px;
    margin-inline-end: 0px;
}
```

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that the Content Box would be the best element to use for what it looks like you're trying to do. I would suggest just building two 1/1 rows within a container and using an image element, then a text element. Use Fusion Builder Live and toggle the wireframe on the get a nice visual of how it's structured.